# merge two DEMs of different resolutions?

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, dem

I have two DEMs, the first one is in 30 meters of résolution and the second: 5 meters, and will like if there is a possibility of merging them to extend the area where I do my research?

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two options.

1. **Mosaic the two rasters to a new raster dataset**, using the [Mosaic to New Raster](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/mosaic-to-new-raster.htm) tool or the [Workspace to Raster Dataset](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/workspace-to-raster-dataset.htm) tool. If you do, you need to choose a single cell size, which means you'll be downsampling the 5-meter DEM or upsampling the 30-meter DEM. (You should add some metadata to the mosaicked raster to explain what you did, especially if you upsample the 30-meter DEM by choosing a cell size of 5 meters. You don't want to make anyone think that the whole raster was originally 5-meter data.)
2. **Create a [mosaic dataset](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/manage-data/raster-and-images/what-is-a-mosaic-dataset.htm)**. That way you're not resampling anything. ArcGIS analysis tools will treat a mosaic dataset as if it were a single raster dataset.

I prefer #2, since it preserves all the original data.